# Is there a microsoft flow function to update a document with last data received?

Tags: excel, vba, pulse

Is there a way to trigger at a time a macro function of an Excel file from Microsoft flow?

Comment: [This](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-microsoft-flow-integration-in-excel/) Might help

Comment: Thanks Dorian. I have the problem that the component should be used by the corporate